# How to install Crypto++5.6.1 library in visual studio 2010

Tags: cryptography

Can any one show how to integrate( or install) crypto++5.6.1 library in visual studio 2010 and one example by using that library with the step by step( It would be great if you show with screenshots).
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

It's rather well documented here: http://cryptopp.com/wiki/Compiling and they have a helpful mailing list too.